# Communication is dropping when printing on my Tevo Tarantula

Tags: marlin, firmware

I am experiencing communication drops when printing from mp raspberryPI (using octoprint, repetitier server). Moreover when printing from Cura (on Windows), the programs freeze (have to kill the window) and sometimes stops the print job.
I was changing the serial0 speed in Marlin from 225k to 9600 and still no luck.
Mainboard MKS 1.4 all in one.

please let me know if you need any  more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per long article [Marlin firmware](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/382)  it looks like my system is a victim of closed ground loop via USB connection. It is now clear to me that printing from laptop (connected to different socket) was a ground loop separated case and therefore the connection was stable. Connecting my raspberryPi from same socket using long unshielded cable is the main reason of connection drops.

Will try to run raspberryPi with short shielded cable and also will test raspberryPi powered from power bank.